# URL regex match with and without query strings

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex which could match the following string under below mentioned condition

```
https://example.com/jobs/2273/software-engineer/job?mobile=true&width=760

Ans: True

https://example.com/jobs/2273/software-engineer/job

Ans:True

https://example.com/jobs/2273/software-engineer/job?mobile=true

Ans: False (should contain both key values as in #1
```

In short the regex should match the url if it end upto `job` as in #2 else if it contains some parameters then it must contain `mobile=true` and `width` both must be present and additional parameters are accepted.

Comment: Assuming no file or directory names contain a question mark, you could use `^(?:(?!.*\?)|\?mobile=(?:true|false)&width=\d+)$`. [ref](https://regex101.com/r/eLc2ee/1/). Not knowing Java, it may be that `\?` must be expressed `\\?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the regex, `(?:.*\/job\?(mobile=(?:true|false)&width=\d+))|(?:.*\/job\?(width=\d+&mobile=(?:true|false)))|.*job(?!.)`

Check [this](https://regex101.com/r/2ApvRG/4) for a quick demo and explanation.

**Demo using Java code:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test URL strings
        String[] urls = { "https://example.com/jobs/2273/software-engineer/job?mobile=true&width=760",
                "https://example.com/jobs/2273/software-engineer/job?mobile=false&width=760",
                "https://example.com/jobs/2273/software-engineer/job?width=760&mobile=true",
                "https://example.com/jobs/2273/software-engineer/job?width=760&mobile=false",
                "https://example.com/jobs/2273/software-engineer/job",
                "https://example.com/jobs/2273/software-engineer/job?mobile=true" };

        String regex = "(?:.*\\/job\\?(mobile=(?:true|false)&width=\\d+))|(?:.*\\/job\\?(width=\\d+&mobile=(?:true|false)))|.*job(?!.)";

        for (String s : urls) {
            System.out.println(s + " => " + s.matches(regex));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
https://example.com/jobs/2273/software-engineer/job?mobile=true&width=760 => true
https://example.com/jobs/2273/software-engineer/job?mobile=false&width=760 => true
https://example.com/jobs/2273/software-engineer/job?width=760&mobile=true => true
https://example.com/jobs/2273/software-engineer/job?width=760&mobile=false => true
https://example.com/jobs/2273/software-engineer/job => true
https://example.com/jobs/2273/software-engineer/job?mobile=true => false
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regular expression. Use the methods in class [`java.net.URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html), namely `getPath()` and `getQuery()`.

According to your question, the string returned by method `getPath()` should end with **job** and method `getQuery()` should either return null or a string that contains both **mobile=** and **width=**

```java
/* import java.net.URL */
URL url = new URL("whatever"); // replace 'whatever' with your actual URL
String path = url.getPath();
if (path.endsWith("job")) {
    String query = url.getQuery();
    if (query == null || (query.contains("mobile=") && query.contains("width=")) {
        // valid
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is really helpful but I was checking whether I can match using regex,

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
.+\/job\b(\?mobile=true\&width=\d+)?$
```

Please check the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/2ApvRG/1)

In Java this must be written something like this:

```
String regex = ".+\\/job\\b(\\?mobile=true\\&width=\\d+)?$";
```